# Mathematical Olympiad Treasures Problem 1.72 missing step

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $s = a + b + c$

It is stated that:

$f(x) = x/(s-x)$ is convex on $(0,s)$

From this the author states:

$f((a+b+c)/3) \leq (f(a) + f(b) + f(c))/3$

This may be very basic but I cannot see why the last step is true. Any help would be appreciated.

To provide further context. It is assumed that all I know about convexity is that $f(\lambda x_a + (1 - \lambda)a_b) \leq \lambda f(x_a) + (1- \lambda) f(x_b)$

Comment: `It is assumed that all I know about convexity is ...` Lookup [Jensen's inequality - Proof 1 (finite form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_.28finite_form.29) for the induction step from $n=2$ to $n=3$..

Comment: In case others cant make the leap, $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right) \le \frac{f(a)+f(b)+f(c)}{3}$ is true because we set $lambda$ to $1/3$

Comment: Right. The end to end derivation goes like: $\\ \require{cancel} f\left(\frac{1}{3} \cdot a+\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{b+c}{2}\right) \le \frac{1}{3} \cdot f(a)+\frac{2}{3} \cdot f\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot b + \frac{1}{2}\cdot c\right) \le \frac{1}{3} \cdot f(a)+ \frac{\bcancel{2}}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\bcancel{2}}\cdot f(b)+\frac{1}{\bcancel{2}}\cdot f(c)\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $f(x) = x/(s-x)$ is convex on $(0,s)$

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{s}{s-x} - 1\,$, then prove it is convex on $\,(0,s)\,$ by the same argument you'd use to prove that $\displaystyle \,\frac{1}{1-x}\,$ is convex on $\,(0,1)\,$.

> $f(a+b+c)/3 \leq (f(a) + f(b) + f(c))/3$

Assuming you meant $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right) \le \frac{f(a)+f(b)+f(c)}{3}$ instead, that's just [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for convex functions. And if it's given that $\,a,b,c \gt 0\,$, then all of $\,a,b,c\,$ fall into the interval $\,(0,s)\,$ where $\,f(x)\,$ was shown to be convex at the previous step.